# Deployment with access Database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, deployment

I am new to vb.net. Here I tried to develop a simple window application and deploy the same with the database. It was successfully working on my pc. But if I install it on another computer it shows an error that the database is not found in the location. I used the data source as my computer location. So, I just want to know how to run it the same on other computers. Thanks.

Comment: What was the process you took to deploy it? Has the database been split? EDIT: Disregard that, didn't read your tags properly, ignore the part about splitting. Though still wondering what was your method to "Deploy" and what do you mean for "I used the data source as my computer location". Can you please give us some relevant settings, otherwise we won't be able to know what's happening.

Comment: The best / simplest way would be to create a setup / deployment project like this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233806%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Does your other computer have access to your database? Can it even see it?

Comment: Check obvious things like whether the other PC has MS Access installed on it and if you've created an installer like a .msi has the database been included in that.